# Why is the following code working with an interface but without any class defined?

Tags: java, class, interface, program-entry-point

```
interface Main 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Inside main");
    int a = 4 , b = 6 ;
    System.out.println(a+b);
}
}
```

In the above code, there is no class defined but the program is still getting executed. But as far as I know, there cannot be any static method inside an Interface. And, every program should contain at least one main function.

Comment: If this works, then "as far as you know" is wrong!

Comment: Java 8 you can do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, you are using Java version 8.

From Java 8 on, you are allowed to have static methods inside an interface.

And main() gets run from interfaces as well (even from enums), as long as you keep the correct signature.